# What is the "CAN YOU HEAR ME?" home item?

Tags: oculus-home

I just opened a couple of reward packs in my Oculus home, and in one of them there was an item with no picture, titled "CAN YOU HEAR ME?". I can not place it and it seems to do nothing. What is this item for, and what can I do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that no image showed up and it could not be placed was a bug. Upon going back to it, it is a postcard.

[image]